# Performance Issue when Single row in Hbase exceeds hbase.hregion.max.filesize

Tags: hadoop, hbase, region

In Hbase, I have configured `hbase.hregion.max.filesize` as 10GB. If the Single row exceeds the 10GB size, then the row will not into 2 regions as Hbase splits are done based on row key

For example, if I have a row which has 1000 columns, and each column varies between 25MB to 40 MB. So there is chance to exceed the defined region size. If this is the case, how will it affect the performance while reading data using rowkey alone or row-key with column qualifier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing is Hbase is NOT for storing that much big data 10GB in a single row(its quite hypothetical).

I hope your have not saved 10GB in a single row (just thinking of saving that)

It will adversely affect the performance. You consider other ways like storing this much data in hdfs in a partitioned structure.

In general, these are the [tips for generally applicable batch clients like Mapreduce Hbase jobs](http://hbase.apache.org/0.94/book/mapreduce.example.html)

```
Scan scan = new Scan();
scan.setCaching(500); //1 is the default in Scan, which will be bad for MapReduce jobs
scan.setCacheBlocks(false);  // don't set to true for MR jobs
```

Can have look at [Performance](http://hbase.apache.org/0.94/book/performance.html)

Comment: Optimal size for the single row in Hbase. Based on that I'll design my row key. Also where can I get these info ?

Comment: AFAIK, there is no optimal size but we have stored proto messages up to 10 mb per row, and processed through mapreduce but then we have to reduce cache size(number of records prefetched) aforementioned 500 to 200. But definitely it can be in mbs not GBs